# replace a line containing sub-string prefixing with the string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I want to prefix/print the string containing the substring as below.
Here, substring I mean VIDIOC and the string here i want to log is VIDIOC_S_CTRL as an example

From:

```
ret = ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_G_FMT, &fmt);
if(ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control)) {
```

To:

```
ALOGI("VIDIOC_G_FMT");    ret = ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_G_FMT, &fmt);
ALOGI("VIDIOC_S_CTRL");    if (ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control)) {
```

I tried to do with **sed** going through web search, But i could not do.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: So you want to replace VIDIOC_G_FMT with VIDIOC

Comment: No, I want to replace a line containing VIDIO* with ALOGI("VIDIOC*");and the original line. please have a look at the example i have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a backreference:

```
sed '/VIDIO/ s/.*\(VIDIO\w*\)/ALOGI("\1");   &/' inputfile
```

or

```
sed -r '/VIDIO/ s/.*(VIDIO\w*)/ALOGI("\1");   &/' inputfile
```

Comment: Excellent. Works as expected.Thanks

Comment: @BalamuruganA: If this answer has worked for you and you are happy with it, please accept it by clicking the tick to the left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`gawk`-Specific

```
awk '{match($0,/VIDIO\w*/,a); print "ALOGI(\""a[0]"\");",$0}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
ALOGI("VIDIOC_G_FMT"); ret = ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_G_FMT, &fmt);
ALOGI("VIDIOC_S_CTRL"); if(ioctl(drv_ctx.video_driver_fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control)) {
```

Comment: Thanks. But, got an error "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ," anyways., devnull's command solved my problem

Comment: `\w` and the 3rd arg to `match()` are non-portable (probably new-ish gawk-only)